# Generating function for maximum of two dice

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Is it possible to make a generating function such that the coefficients provide the number of ways that the maximum of two dice can be obtained?

For the sum of dice, I know that the generating function is simply:

$$f(x) = x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6$$

And reading the coefficients of $f(x)^2$ gives the probability distribution.

i.e $$f(x)^2 = (x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)(x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)$$

$$f(x)^2 = 1x^{12} + 2x^{11} + 3x^{10} + 4x^{9} + 5x^8 + 6x^7 + 5x^6 + 4x^5 + 3x^4 + 2x^3 + 1x^2 $$

There are 6 ways to get a sum of 7, reading the coefficient of $x^7$.

What is $g(x)$ for the maximum of two dice?

For example rolling a 2 and a 3 will output a 3. Rolling a 4 and a 4 will output 4.

Comment: what do you mean by And reading the coefficients of f(x)^2 gives the probability distribution?

Comment: for the maximum of two dice, does "brute force solution" (enumerate all possibilities) work?

Comment: @DanielS. I suspect that this was an attempt to say $f(x)$ is the generating function for a single roll of a die and so $f(x)^2$  is the generating function for the sum of two independent dice rolls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For fixed $n \ge 1$ the number of pairs $(i,j) \in \mathbf{N}^2$ such that $\max(i,j) = n$ is $2n-1$. So the polynomial (generating function) whose coefficient of $x^n$ counts the number of ways to roll two (six-sided) dice and get a max of $n$ is $x + 3x^2 + 5x^3 + 7x^4 + 9x^5 + 11x^6$.

Comment: Can you generalise this to a higher number of dice? Maybe for n dice?

Comment: @Triple_1: It is not difficult: what have you tried? As a clue: $1+3=4, 4+5=9, 9+7=16$ etc.

Comment: I found that for three dice, the possible number of pairs is $n³ - (n-1)³ $. This should mean that for k dice, the number of pairs is $n^k - (n-1)^k$. Is this right?

Comment: @Triple_1 Your answer for $k$ dice is correct. Can you prove it?

Comment: If a k-dimensional cube were to be represented in a plane where each of the coordinates refer to a dice roll, then the maximum of any number n is just the outer shell. I dont know if there is way to do this analytically though.

Comment: @Triple_1 There are $(n-1)^k$ many ways we can roll $k$ dice such that all of the numbers are strictly less than $n$. There are $n^k$ many ways to have every number less than or equal to $n$. The difference $n^k - (n-1)^k$ thus counts the number of ways to roll an outcome that contains at least one $n$ and such that this is the max among the rolled numbers.